# Хочу сделать так, чтобы враг при нахождении рядом направился ко мне (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я делаю игру про зомби, там нужно сделать так, чтобы когда я находился рядом с зомби он двигался ко мне, чтобы убить меня. Я сделал скрипт, но он направляется ко мне когда я нажимаю старт (скрипт смотрел с ютуба), а мне нужно тогда, когда я рядом с ним. Можете сказать как это сделать? Вот мой код.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{

public float speed = 3;
public Transform target;

void Start()
{
    target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Transform>();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}
}
```

Comment: Так длину вектора проеряйте, расстояние. Если больше порогового, то ничего не делать.

Comment: я сам недавно начал делать игры и не знаю как это делать :)